# Laravel vagrant refused connection

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I have a web app with laravel 5.1 without install homestead.

Now I have to do a multiple connect in my web app, and the second db is on Vagrant.

So I have created a second connection in **database.php**

```
'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.33.10',
            'database'  => 'name_db',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => ''
        ],
```

In my vagrant file I put this :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

So I have to call the db on vagrant machine and in my controller I have a function:

```
public function devices(){
         Device::all();
    }
```

And the model is:

```
class Device extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table ="table";
}
```

But I have this error

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Unable
>   to establish connection. Persistent computer refusal.

But If I try to write the **192.168.33.10 on my addressbar** it return the apache start page, and if I write **192.168.33.10/phpmyadmin** I correctly see a phpmyadmin service.

What I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't see a port specified in your config array. Are you sure it isn't trying to connect on a wrong port?

Comment: Use laradock instead, it's faster and preconfigured for laravel https://github.com/laradock/laradock

Comment: gbalduzzi, yes, I've tried with port => '3306' and port=>'33060' but it doesn't work.

Comment: thankyou @veNuker I never use laradock, but I have to install a particulary software, in laradock I can install what I want?

Comment: You can fork "laradock" repository and do whatever you want. But check documentation first, it can already have the software you want, for example: `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql memcached redis` will run all mentioned apps for you in seconds :)